# RSA key conversion from Uint8Array to BigInteger with node-rsa

Tags: javascript, encryption, integer, rsa

I have a generated RSA key in the format of `Uint8Array` but I need the key in the format of BigInteger. See images below. How can I achieve such a conversion?

[image]

[image]

I use the node RSA lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the ‘generated’ key was obtained by invoking the [`exportKey` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa#importexport-keys), using the ‘components’ format.  With this setting, this method [returns a fixed-structure object whose values are `Buffer`s holding individual key components](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa/blob/b7c743d5cd4d35e462b533ba6a3c78eb24dd2589/src/formats/components.js#L5-L16); it also appears that you have installed some kind of shim that simulates [the node.js `Buffer` API](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) with the [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/uint8array) object that browsers provide.

If that is so, then it all it should take to get the key object back is to invoke the [`importKey` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa#importexport-keys):

```js
const key = new NodeRSA();
key.importKey(keyData, 'components');
```